# "is_edited": false or "is_edited": true as an option in the API response

Tags: support, feature-request, api, editing

When working with the Stack Exchange API I noticed that there is important data (at least for what I thought to do) not available, whether the question, answer or comment was edited or not:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "flutter",
        "dart"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "account_id": 4684815,
        "reputation": 4503,
        "user_id": 3792482,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 43,
        "profile_image": "https://graph.facebook.com/100000271181489/picture?type=large",
        "display_name": "phongyewtong",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/3792482/phongyewtong"
      },
      "is_answered": false,
      "view_count": 2,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "last_activity_date": 1652287746,
      "creation_date": 1652287746,
      "question_id": 72204805,
      "content_license": "CC BY-SA 4.0",
      "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72204805/flutter-doughnut-chart-has-hugh-margin-padding-how-to-remove",
      "title": "flutter doughnut chart has hugh margin/padding. how to remove?"
    }
```

I understand that there is a way to reach this result (I confess that I'm not completely and absolutely sure about that) by taking the value of `"creation_date"` and seeing if it is equal to `"last_activity_date"`, but to speed up the work of a code, if we had this value already in the API response, it would be perfect.

I think it would be interesting if we had:

```
"is_edited": false
```

or

```
"is_edited": true
```

Please, if can confirm if `"creation_date" == "last_activity_date"` gets the same result, that would be an important answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a `last_edited_date` on [questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question), [answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer) and [posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post). If it's empty (and you did include it in your filter), it hasn't been edited.

[Comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment) have a built-in `edited` field which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: In my filter, how should I set ```last_edit_date``` it to ```null``` so that it only returns questions that have no edit? I confess that in the documentation I could not understand its use. To help, this is my url today: ```https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/no-answers?pagesize=30&fromdate={date_today}&order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow``` Because as the null return is empty, I didn't understand how it would enter the url. Thanks for support @Glorfindel!

Comment: That is not possible. I know the word 'filter' suggests that, but it only filters the *output*. The API only supports the parameters visible in the 'form' on the documentation page. You would need to use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to do that, but SEDE is updated only once a week.